# Get a JSON API extension in a List

Tags: c#, json, uwp

I have a SQL database that consists of rooms and I´m getting the values from the database via an API. Right now I have a `List` with the rooms and their attributes.

The URL from where I get those values:

```
string url = "https://api.booking.com/api/room";
```

Every room has its own image but the url where the images are looks like this:

```
string url = "https://api.booking.com/api/room/35bf3c4d-9b5b-40fd-bcf4-a4c2c6c564bc/image";
```

The `Guid` is the id of a room.

The rest of the attributes is in the first URL and I have no problem reaching them, but my problem is that i don't know what I should do to get the images into the list with the other attributes.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Add route attribute for actionresult with `api/room/{roomid}/image` and while calling this, pass roomid with that. Have a look at this [MS DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2)

Comment: @mmushtaq I'm sorry but i can't really understand how you mean... i want to have the images in a attribute so i just can implement a room and the image goes with it automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to have two classes - one for parsing of the JSON from the first URL (which will not have this image attribute), and then one model class that will represent the room in your app. Then this class will have properties for the attributes from JSON as well as a URI or `ImageSource` property for the image.

In this case having just the URI to the image seems like a better solution, because you don't have to keep all the images in memory and can just bind the URI to a image component and the system will take care of downloading and displaying.

If you don't need two layers of data models, you could just add another property to the first JSON class for the image URI and just parse the first API and then assign the URI separately.

Finally, in case the second URL is just the path to the image, you could just auto-generate it:

```
public Uri ImageUrl => 
   new Uri( $"https://api.booking.com/api/room/{Id}/image", UriKind.Absolute );
```

Assuming you have another property `Id` which is the `Guid` of the room.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I Will test the solution and come back with a result as soon as possible... You are right the `guid` is a `id` :)

Comment: If it doesn't help, please add an example of the JSON from the API to your question

Comment: Awesome :-) ! Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks! The same to you! :)